# A manga with a scene of a group entering a city and learning that they have to pay 10 silver to leave

Tags: arata-the-legend

I'm sorry, I can't be too specific, since I only read 1 volume in a library.

Here's what I remember about the volume 6:

- There's a group of fighters who want to meet this powerful villain, and on their adventure, they travel into a city. However, it costs 10 silver to enter and leave the city, so they have to work there to pay their debt.
- The three boys in the group decide to work in a quarry, but the pay sucks. They work for several hours but only receive 38 bronze.
- Then, a man introduces them to a new job of washing girl's backs, which pays 1 silver for every customer. Two of the boys are excited to do it (one of them being the main character), while the other boy refuses, saying that girls are generally the ones washing his back.
- After a while, the two boys spot a girl and both rush over to wash her back, and the main character ends up knocking the girl over and lands on top of her. It turns out that the girl is actually his partner. She throws a bucket at him while he tries to apologize and leaves the bath. This makes the main character depressed.
- In the end, he earns 30 silver to share with the other boy he was working with. However, the man who introduced them to the job demands a finder's fee of 29 silver.

Okay, I think that's more than enough. Thanks in advance if you can help me :D!

Answer (score 5):

**[Arata Kangatari](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=37033)** is the series you are looking for.

It took some thinking, since I dropped it a few years ago, but what you remember is from chapter 53 of the series.

Here is the last page of the chapter:

[image: Last page of chapter 53]

Synopsis of **[Arata Kangatari](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=37033)** from mangaupdates:

> [image: Cover]
>
> Every 30 years, a new princess is chosen from the Hime family to serve the Hayagami. The time has come again, but over these past years, records state not a single female has been born, save for one, the 15-year-old Arata. The only problem is, Arata is actually a male! Forced to disguise himself and take the place of the princess candidate until a formal one can be found, he attends the festival only to witness the current princess, Kokuri-hime, murdered, and his own life is forfeit as well, by the hands of the princess' personal guard, the 12 Shinshou. As he runs for his life, Kannagi of the 12 convinces everyone that Arata is the one who has murdered the princess instead, and now everyone in the Imperial Court is after his head! Now, another Arata from our world has crossed over in Arata's place! How did this happen, and how will these two survive?
>
> [arata-kangatari](/questions/tagged/arata-kangatari)